# asp.net mvc controller arguments a?b1,c2... how to parse variable number?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

If a URL, in asp.net mvc, has args that are not catered for in the index/show method signature of a controller, is it possible to use something like a params string[] args in the signature to gather them up. Or what is a good way to do this when the arg is a list of separated values (ie not name/value pairs)?

We have users, ultimately, creating urls with a variable number of arguments & need to parse them.

This is the code we have at the moment, but we can't help thinking there's a better way without splitting the string ourselves:

```
var url = Request.RawUrl.Split('?');

   if (url.Length > 1)
   {
     var queryString = url[1];
     var queryStringArgs = queryString.Split('&');
     var queryStringMembers = from arg in queryStringArgs
             let c = arg.Split('=').Length == 1
             where c 
             select arg;
     ViewBag.QueryStringMembers = queryStringMembers.ToJson();    
   }
```

*Append: these args dont have name=value, it's just a list of values.
Request.QueryString doesn't seem to help us, as it treats these query string args differently because they are not name=value, they are just value. So it puts them in a Request.QueryString[null] key as comma separated

Comment: Is there a fixed set of combinations that they might "generate" or are there too many to list?

Comment: As I am working with the poster on this issue..  They can have as many additional args as they like that are not name=value, they will just be value.

Comment: sorry, yes I've appended the question "these args dont have name=value, it's just a list of values"

Answer (score 1):

First things first what you have is a malformed URL. So you are totally on your own parsing it. You may also expect it to fail any time. Everything that is part of the querystring, i.e. following the first `?`, must be url encoded, you should not have multiple `?`.

This being said you could write a custom model binder:

```
public class CustomModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var tokens = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl.Split('?');
        if (tokens.Length > 1) 
        {
            return tokens.Skip(1).ToArray();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

and then:

```
public ActionResult Index([ModelBinder(typeof(CustomModelBinder))]string[] args)
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: You're right about the URL malformed - that was my mistake, the URL actually doesn't have multiple ?, so we're good on that front.

Answer (score 0):

`Request.QueryString.AllKeys` will contain a string array of the argument names sent in on the QueryString. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Request.QueryString treats these query string args differently because they are not name=value, they are just value.  So it puts them in a Request.QueryString[null] key as comma seperated.  This hurts as well because there maybe a comma (even if its encoded) in the arg.